# My class executed before. But now it doesn't. Execute Anonymous Error Invalid Type Line 1 Column 1

Tags: batch, developer-console, execute-anonymous

I am 12-years into Salesforce BUT new to APEX coding and am writing a class to simply trigger an update on all records on `Budget__c` in order to fire some declarative workflow rules (if anyone has ideas on how to improve the class, please suggest).

The main problem is I am getting an

> Execute Anonymous Error Line 1 Column 1 Invalid Type: batchBudgetMonthlyUpdate.

But this did work and now it doesn't. I don't think I changed anything but maybe I did. The only thing I can think of is I tested it, it worked, then I logged out of sandbox and into production. When I logged back into sandbox, is when it stopped working. I tried checking environment but cannot figure out if this is related or not.

```
// Batch Job for updating all Budget records on the 1st of each month
// 23 April 2020 by Tom Barber cloudconsulting, LLC
global class BudgetMonthlyUpdate implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
global String [] email = new String[] {'tbarber@cloudconsultingllc.com'};
// Email address is used below to send batch job status messages

// Start Method
global Database.Querylocator start (Database.BatchableContext BC) {
  return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT id FROM Budget__c');
  // Query to get all the Budget__c object record IDs from all the Budget__c records--no WHERE statement
}

// Execute method
global void execute (Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Budget__c> scope) {
   for(Budget__c a : scope)
   {a.Id = a.Id;
   }

  if (scope != null && scope.size()>0) {
     // Check if List is empty or not
     Database.update(scope); System.debug('List Size'
        + scope.size());
     // Update the Budget records-doesn't change the value of any record. Basically is a trigger     to update all
  }
}

// Finish Method
   global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
   Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

  // The code below will fetch the job Id
  AsyncApexJob a = [Select a.TotalJobItems, a.Status, a.NumberOfErrors,
  a.JobType, a.JobItemsProcessed, a.ExtendedStatus, a.CreatedById,
  a.CompletedDate From AsyncApexJob a WHERE id = :BC.getJobId()];//get the job Id
  System.debug('$$$ Jobid is '+BC.getJobId());
   String APEXjobID = null;
   APEXjobID = +BC.getJobId();

  // the code below will send an email to User about the job status
  mail.setToAddresses(email);
  mail.setReplyTo('tbarber@cloudconsultingllc.com'); //Add your email address here
  mail.setSenderDisplayName('RLG Salesforce Apex Batch Processing');
  mail.setSubject('Monthly Budget Update Batch Processing: '+a.Status);
  mail.setPlainTextBody('Apex job ' + APEXjobID +' | Monthly Budget Update completed' + a.CompletedDate + 'with status: ' + a.ExtendedStatus
                        + '\n' + 'This job runs on the 1st of each month and updates all the Budget records on the object so the current month (and year) checkboxes are checked.'
                        + '\n' + a.TotalJobItems+ ' batches with '+a.NumberOfErrors+' failures.'
                        + '\n' + 'Job Items processed:' +a.JobItemsProcessed);
  Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.Singleemailmessage [] {mail});
 }
}
```

Comment: Where are you receiving this error, in execute anonymous window? If yes, can you also post the snippet you are using to schedule/execute this batch?

Comment: Side note, if this is a one-time need, it's easy to do with Data Loader. Just map Id to Id and run an update operation.

Comment: Thanks Jayant and David. Yes, the error is in the execute anonymous window. Snippet below. Thanks for the Dataloader suggestion however this will be a scheduled batch through the UI on the 1st of every month.

Comment: `batchBudgetMonthlyUpdate b = new batchBudgetMonthlyUpdate();
        database.executeBatch(b);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in your comments, you are using the following snippet to execute a batch class which is named `BudgetMonthlyUpdate`:

```
batchBudgetMonthlyUpdate b = new batchBudgetMonthlyUpdate(); 
Database.executeBatch(b);
```

This is the source of the error you have, where you have prefixed additional text *batch* to the class name.

> Error Line 1 Column 1 Invalid Type: batchBudgetMonthlyUpdate

To create the instance and execute the batch, you will need to use the class name as-is without any prefix. The correct snippet would be:

```
BudgetMonthlyUpdate b = new BudgetMonthlyUpdate(); 
Database.executeBatch(b);
```

Comment: Thanks Jayant. Typical newbie error: answer hidden in plain sight. :) I also need help with the test class for this. I wrote one to insert records. It worked but it had 0% coverage. Thinking I have to write one that updates records but getting stuck on what the class should have.

    Will insert provide coverage? or do I have to write an update test (if so, what this class does is so simple, can't I just repeat what's in it for the test?)
    What would the assert statement look like?
    Does the test class have to test the finish statements that send out the single email?

Comment: @cloudconsulting Yes you will need to write test class for this for sure. A good starting point on how to get started can be found on [this link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canonical-qa) on SFSE. Primarily you need to ensure you are testing your batch class and that if it is updating records, then you are asserting those updates by fetching those records in your test class.

Comment: Thanks again. I will check that out. Follow up: so if I fetch just one record and update it with the test class, should that do it? (the object has ~70,000 records)

Comment: Ideally Yes. Take a look at trailhead/docs for more pointers on specifically testing apex batch. A good place to start is [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/asynchronous_apex/async_apex_batch#Tdxn4tBK-heading7)